# 2D array 100x100 stack overflow; no error on heap. c++

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've made a 2D array on the stack by doing:

```
    grid gridArray[100][100] = {{}};
```

However, I get a stack overflow.

```
auto gridArray = new grid[100][100]();
```

If i put it on the heap, I don't get an error.

I don't exactly know why this is; is the stack unable to allocate as much memory as the heap? Is there any danger in the way I'm doing it now?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of grid data structure..?

Comment: Remember that the stack is a limited memory area, usually 1, 2 or 4 MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't exactly know why this is; is the stack unable to allocate as much memory as the heap?

That's exactly it. Stack space is limited. As a rule of thumb, if you have more than a few KB of data you should use the heap.

See: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)